# SQL - Buscando produto mais vendido em um intervalo de data

Tags: sql

Estou tentando buscar com SQL o produto mais vendido dentro de um determinado periodo. Para isso, possuo a tabela 'conta_produtos', que possui as seguintes colunas:

id (PK) | conta_id (FK) | produto_id (FK) | precoFinal | created_at | updated_at

Pois bem, possuo, obviamente, a tabela `produto` e a tabela `contas`.

Antes eu já havia feito um SQL que consegue buscar o produto mais vendido utilizando um 'count', ordenando descendente e limitando o resultado ao mais vendido, da seguinte forma:

```
SELECT nome, urlImagem
FROM produtos
WHERE id = (
    SELECT produto_id
    FROM conta_produtos
    GROUP BY produto_id
    ORDER BY count(*) DESC
    LIMIT 1
);
```

Mas agora estou querendo limitar este SQL para um determinado período, ou seja, buscar qual foi o produto mais vendido em um determinado intervalo de data.

Então acredito que tenho que mudar o SELECT de dentro. Mudei ele, tentei elaborar um raciocínio, mas infelizmente o SQL tem algum erro e eu não consigo enxergar qual é.
Meu SQL:

```
SELECT produto_id
FROM conta_produtos
GROUP BY produto_id
ORDER BY count(*) DESC
WHERE updated_at BETWEEN '2017-03-03' AND '2017-03-08'
```

O que eu percebi foi que se eu colocar a última linha (a linha principal do meu sql, porque faz o filtro de data), o SQL não funciona. Este group by id irá pegar a data mais recente entre dois IDs iguais? Será que isso que está atrapalhando meu where?

Obrigado!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A cláusula WHERE deve vir antes do GROUP BY e do ORDER BY. Exemplo:

```
SELECT produto_id
FROM conta_produtos
WHERE updated_at BETWEEN '2017-03-03' AND '2017-03-08' 
GROUP BY produto_id
ORDER BY count(*) DESC
```

Comment: Excelente. Obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Tirando o fato que o group by e order by devem vir no final, depois do where, pode ser interessante incluir a coluna count com um apelido.

```
SELECT 
    produto_id, count(produto_id) as contagem_produto
FROM 
    conta_produtos
WHERE 
    updated_at BETWEEN '2017-03-03' AND '2017-03-08' 
GROUP BY 
    produto_id
ORDER BY 
    contagem_produto DESC
```